# Java Tetris Game: Having trouble visualizing how to move an object Piece of 4 distinct Tile objects

Tags: java, swing

I'm making Tetris as a fun side project in Java.

I'm at the point where I'm trying to move a full tetris Piece, which is an Object composed of 4 Tile objects.

When I move the piece down, all the blocks that are unobstructed by one of the other tiles
will move down without issue. Any part of the Piece that's blocked by one of its tiles (in example, that'd be the tile with a blue x) won't move due to these two checks:

[image]

```
public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height-1; 
}

public boolean isOpen(int x, int y) {
        return isValidCoordinate(x, y) && getTileAt(x, y) == null;
}
```

From Board class, I move the Piece object as such:

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

newPiece.movePieceDown();
```

Then in Piece class:

```
    public void movePieceDown() {
    tile1.setLocation(tile1.getX(), tile1.getY()+1);
    tile2.setLocation(tile2.getX(), tile2.getY()+1);
    tile3.setLocation(tile3.getX(), tile3.getY()+1);
    tile4.setLocation(tile4.getX(), tile4.getY()+1);        
}
```

Is there a way I can make it so that all tiles of the Tetris piece will move together?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

**EXE:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mg9dtf2sr0sazwq/my_tetris_test2.jar

**Source:**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kt3sl6qqo54amk/Tetris%20Two.rar

---

**CODE EDIT:**

Testing with reverse Z shape:

[image]

Starting Coordinates: `Piece "RevZ" Coordinates: (1, 1) (2, 1) (0, 2) (1, 2)`

Pressing down key gives me:

[image]

**Board.java class:** Changed the key event to this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        newPiece.movePieceCheck(keyCode);
        if (newPiece.movePieceValid()) {
            newPiece.move();
        }
        repaint();  
}
```

**Piece.java class:** I now check before I move...

```
public void calcNewPosition(int newX, int newY, int currTile) {     
    newPositionX[currTile] = newX;
    newPositionY[currTile] = newY;
    System.out.println("New Position: " + newPositionX[currTile] + ", " + newPositionY[currTile]);  
}

public void clearCurrPosition(int currX, int currY, int currTile) { 
        currPositionX[currTile] = currX;
        currPositionY[currTile] = currY;    
        System.out.println("Current Position: " + currPositionX[currTile] + ", " + currPositionY[currTile]);
        board.setTileAt(null, currPositionX[currTile], currPositionY[currTile]);
        if (board.getTileAt(currPositionX[currTile], currPositionY[currTile]) == null) {
            System.out.println("curr block set to null...");
    }       
}       

public void movePieceCheck(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY()+1, i);
            clearCurrPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY(), i);
        }       
    }
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX()+1, tile[i].getY(), i);
            clearCurrPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY(), i);
        }       
    }
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
            calcNewPosition(tile[i].getX()-1, tile[i].getY(), i);
            clearCurrPosition(tile[i].getX(), tile[i].getY(), i);
        }       
    }
}

public boolean movePieceValid() {   
    boolean valid = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
        if(tile[i].checkNewLocation(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i])) {
            valid = true;
        }
    }       
    return valid;
}       

public void move()   {
    for (int i = 0; i < tile.length; i++) {
        tile[i].setLocation(newPositionX[i], newPositionY[i]);              
    }       
}
```

**Println Output:**

```
Piece "RevZ" Coordinates: (1, 1) (2, 1) (0, 2) (1, 2) 

New Position: 1, 2
Current Position: 1, 1
curr block set to null...
New Position: 2, 2
Current Position: 2, 1
curr block set to null...
New Position: 0, 3
Current Position: 0, 2
curr block set to null...
New Position: 1, 3
Current Position: 1, 2
curr block set to null...
```

---

I'm checking all first like you said, and THEN setting the location.

The problem is now, it's moving all except the block that wasn't able to move when the check occurred because the original piece was there. But that's weird because I set that old location to null before I move the pieces so it should be empty.

Comment: Create a class TetrisPiece that holds multiple TetrisBlocks, and have the first class check for obstructions and control the movement of its constituent blocks. This is nothing more than basic OOPs design, I think.

Comment: just add a check to see if `getTileAt(x,y)` == tile[1-4]

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's what I did. Piece is that class that hold multiple TetrisBlocks (tiles). I have 4 classes: `Tetris.java` which creates the JPanel, `Board.java` which instantiates the grid of tiles, and has collision/endgame, getTile location checks, etc..., `Tile.java` which is the tetris piece, and `Piece.java` which is 4 Tile objects.... it gets a `randomPiece` parameter which set's the initial Shape (by setting each of the 4 tiles' coordinates)

Comment: @AlexGittemeier I was thinking of doing that, but wasn't sure how to iterate through the 4 tiles of the tetris Piece from the Board class

Comment: You could pass a reference of the `PieceClass` to `isOpen()`, but that would necesitate having public getters for the tiles in a piece.

Comment: If done correctly, the code should work. It the TetrisPiece should be able to iterate through its blocks calling moveDown() on each block. You must have a bug in your code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah that's what I was thinking... I'm not sure why they won't all move down in succession

Comment: You're hard-coding your iteration through the tiles which is not good and prone to bugs. You should instead iterate through the *collection* of tiles which constitute your piece. Also, have you used a debugger or used debug statements to evaluate the state of your objects during program run?

Comment: @AlexGittemeier Should I instantiate Piece as an array of tiles and try and iterate through the instance?

Comment: No Growler, again, use a ***collection*** of tiles.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not understanding what you mean by collection. The Piece class *is* a collection of 4 tile objects.

Comment: I mean ***Collection*** precisely, one of the classes of the Collection library. How does Piece hold its Tiles? Again it should hold them in a ***Collection*** such as an `ArrayList<Tile>`. You should not make the code so rigid as to hold 4 and only 4 pieces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25818/discussion-between-growler-and-hovercraft-full-of-eels)

Comment: Please don't post off site links to your code. Instead, please check what I did to make one file that runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this isn't to strange, since you as you say check to se if the position is `valid` that is, as i understand it, that no other piece is there.

Your problem is this:

```
tile3.setLocation(tile3.getX(), tile3.getY()+1);
tile4.setLocation(tile4.getX(), tile4.getY()+1);
```

I'm betting that it is piece 3 that gets stuck. So to solve this just change the order of these two. But now comes the problem, what happens when you rotate the piece, in which order should they then be moved?

I think it would be better to first calculate the new position of each square, remove them from their current position. And then draw them all into their new position:

```
calculateNewPositions();
clearCurrentPositions();
drawSquares();
```

This should be possible to make quite general without to much trouble so it can handle the different cases(i.e when you rotate the object) without to much hassle.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for the answer. I tried what you said (please see above), but it's still giving me similar issues. The print statements show that: 1) the new positions are being accurately calculated and stored, 2) the old positions are set to null... Then I set the location of the blocks to the new location. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is one of logic where each Tile is deciding if its blocked and moving which is wrong. Suggestions:

- The Tile class should not decide whether it should move or not.
- Instead it should have a method that checks if it is not blocked, and that's it.
- The Piece class should iterate through its Tile collection call this methods on its constituent Tile objects.
- If a Tile is blocked, Piece should make sure that it is not being blocked by one of its own Tiles.
- If the Tile is blocked by a non-Piece Tile, then Piece should call off the move.
- If all the Tiles are not blocked, or if any Tile is blocked by a Tile from its own Piece then Piece should iterate through the Tile `ArrayList<Tile>` telling each Tile to move.

For the benefit of others, here is your complete program in a single file:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TetrisSscce extends JPanel {
   static TetrisSscce runMe;
   BoardSscce board;

   public TetrisSscce() { // creates a new Panel window and sets properties
      JFrame f = new JFrame("Tetris");
      // width (height), length, tilesize
      board = new BoardSscce(4, 6, 30);
      f.add(board);
      f.setSize(board.getWidth(), board.getHeight());
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setResizable(false);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Dimension screensize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      f.setLocation((screensize.width - f.getWidth()) / 2,
            (screensize.height - f.getHeight()) / 2 - 100);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      runMe = new TetrisSscce();
   }

}

class BoardSscce extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
   private TileSscce grid[][];
   private TileSscce activetile;
   private int width, height, tilesize;
   private String piece;
   private PieceSscce newPiece;

   public BoardSscce(int w, int h, int ts) { // add elements to the Tetris panel
      width = w;
      height = h;
      tilesize = ts;
      grid = new TileSscce[height][width];

      // activetile = new TileSscce(this,0, 0); //add new tile to "this" board

      newPiece = new PieceSscce(this, randomPiece());

      addKeyListener(this);
      setFocusable(true);

   }

   public String randomPiece() {
      String[] Pieces = { "L", "O", "Z", "RevZ", "Bar", "T", "RevL" };
      String randomShape;

      int rand = (int) (Math.random() * Pieces.length);
      randomShape = Pieces[rand];

      return randomShape;
   }

   // dimensions of board = width * tilesize
   public int getWidth() {
      // 4 * 30 = 120 width
      return width * tilesize;
   }

   public int getHeight() {
      // 6 * 30 = 180 height
      return height * tilesize;
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
      for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
         for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
            if (grid[row][col] != null) {
               // if there is a non-null space, that is a tetris piece.. fill it
               // red
               if (grid[row][col].getColor() != null) {
                  g.setColor(grid[row][col].getColor());
                  g.fillRect(col * tilesize, row * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
         // checkBottomFull(0,4);
         // collisionCheck(activetile.getX(),activetile.getY());
         // checkEndGame(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY());

         // activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1);

         // need to move Object newPiece down as a unit of 4 tiles
         newPiece.movePieceDown();

         // System.out.println("coordinates: " + activetile.getX() + ", " +
         // activetile.getY());

         repaint();
      }
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
         // activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX()+1, activetile.getY());
         // System.out.println("coordinates: " + activetile.getX() + ", " +
         // activetile.getY());
         newPiece.movePieceRight();
         repaint();
      }
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
         // activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX()-1, activetile.getY());
         // System.out.println("coordinates: " + activetile.getX() + ", " +
         // activetile.getY());
         newPiece.movePieceLeft();
         repaint();
      }

   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
   }

   // check if (x, y) is a safe coordinate, ie, within the grid array bounds
   public boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
      return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height - 1;
   }

   // returns the tile at (x, y) or null if empty
   public TileSscce getTileAt(int x, int y) {
      if (isValidCoordinate(x, y))
         return grid[y][x];
      return null;
   }

   // sets the tile at (x, y) to tile
   public void setTileAt(TileSscce tile, int x, int y) {
      if (isValidCoordinate(x, y))
         grid[y][x] = tile;
   }

   public boolean isOpen(int x, int y) {
      return isValidCoordinate(x, y) && getTileAt(x, y) == null;
   }

   public void collisionCheck(int x, int y) {
      /*
       * if (activetile.getY() == this.height-2 || getTileAt(x, y+1) != null) {
       * //activetile = new TileSscce(this, 0, 0); newPiece = new
       * PieceSscce(this, randomPiece()); }
       */

   }

   public void checkBottomFull(int x, int y) {
      while (getTileAt(x, y) != null) {
         say("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
         if (x == 3) {
            say("row is full");
            // replace full row with tiles from above
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
                  grid[j][i] = getTileAt(i, j - 1);
               }
            }
            break;
         }
         x++;
      }
   }

   public void checkEndGame(int x, int y) {
      if (y == 0 && !isOpen(x, y + 1)) {
         say("Game over");
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j > 0; j--) {
               grid[j][i] = null;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void say(String word) {
      System.out.println(word);
   }

   public void sayint(int number) {
      System.out.println(number);
   }
}

class PieceSscce {
   public int[] pieceCoordinates;
   public String shape;
   public BoardSscce board;

   public TileSscce tile[];

   public TileSscce tile1;
   public TileSscce tile2;
   public TileSscce tile3;
   public TileSscce tile4;

   // don't need to pass in board because I'm already utilizing the Tiles class,
   // which knows about the board
   public PieceSscce(BoardSscce b, String randomPiece) {
      shape = randomPiece;
      board = b;
      // set what the shape coordinates should be based on what "shape" is

      pieceCoordinates = new int[8];
      setInitialShapeCoordinates(shape);

      tile = new TileSscce[4];

      tile1 = new TileSscce(board, pieceCoordinates[0], pieceCoordinates[1]);
      tile2 = new TileSscce(board, pieceCoordinates[2], pieceCoordinates[3]);
      tile3 = new TileSscce(board, pieceCoordinates[4], pieceCoordinates[5]);
      tile4 = new TileSscce(board, pieceCoordinates[6], pieceCoordinates[7]);

   }

   public void movePieceDown() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

      }

      tile1.setLocation(tile1.getX(), tile1.getY() + 1);
      tile2.setLocation(tile2.getX(), tile2.getY() + 1);
      tile3.setLocation(tile3.getX(), tile3.getY() + 1);
      tile4.setLocation(tile4.getX(), tile4.getY() + 1);
   }

   public void movePieceRight() {

      tile1.setLocation(tile1.getX() + 1, tile1.getY());
      tile2.setLocation(tile2.getX() + 1, tile2.getY());
      tile3.setLocation(tile3.getX() + 1, tile3.getY());
      tile4.setLocation(tile4.getX() + 1, tile4.getY());
   }

   public void movePieceLeft() {

      tile1.setLocation(tile1.getX() - 1, tile1.getY());
      tile2.setLocation(tile2.getX() - 1, tile2.getY());
      tile3.setLocation(tile3.getX() - 1, tile3.getY());
      tile4.setLocation(tile4.getX() - 1, tile4.getY());
   }

   public void setInitialShapeCoordinates(String shape) {
      System.out.println(shape);
      if (shape == "L") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 1;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 1;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 2;

      } else if (shape == "O") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 1;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 2;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 2;

      } else if (shape == "Z") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 1;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 2;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 2;

      } else if (shape == "RevZ") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 1;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 2;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 2;

      } else if (shape == "Bar") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 1;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 1;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 3;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 1;

      } else if (shape == "T") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 1;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 2;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 2;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 2;

      } else if (shape == "RevL") {
         // piece 1
         pieceCoordinates[0] = 0;
         pieceCoordinates[1] = 2;

         // piece2
         pieceCoordinates[2] = 1;
         pieceCoordinates[3] = 2;

         // piece3
         pieceCoordinates[4] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[5] = 2;

         // piece4
         pieceCoordinates[6] = 2;
         pieceCoordinates[7] = 1;

      }
   }
}

class TileSscce {
   private BoardSscce board;
   private int currX, currY;

   public TileSscce(BoardSscce b, int x, int y) {
      board = b;

      // when TileSscce is instantiated, set its position
      setLocation(x, y);
   }

   public int getX() {
      return currX;
   }

   public int getY() {
      return currY;
   }

   public void setLocation(int newX, int newY) {
      if (board.isValidCoordinate(newX, newY) && board.isOpen(newX, newY)) {

         board.setTileAt(null, currX, currY);
         currX = newX;
         currY = newY;
         board.setTileAt(this, currX, currY);

      }
   }

   public Color getColor() {

      double rand = Math.random() * (2 - 0);

      /*
       * Random rand = new Random(); float r = rand.nextFloat(); float g =
       * rand.nextFloat(); float b = rand.nextFloat();
       */
      // Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);

      if (rand == 1) {
         return Color.GRAY;
      } else {
         return Color.RED;
      }
   }

   public Color setColor() {
      return Color.GREEN;
   }
}
```

As Daniel points out, you need to split your logic on how to check for blocked pieces and how to move. You should first check for blocks on all the Tiles held by a piece, and then have the Piece tell all the tiles to move instead of what you're doing -- checking each piece for a block and then moving it if unblocked.

For example, giving Tile something like so:

```
// method to check if position OK
public boolean checkNewLocation(int newX, int newY) {
  boolean newLocationOK = board.isValidCoordinate(newX, newY)
        && board.isOpen(newX, newY);

  return newLocationOK;
}

// method to move to new position.
public void setLocation(int newX, int newY) {
  board.setTileAt(null, currX, currY);
  currX = newX;
  currY = newY;
  board.setTileAt(this, currX, currY);
}
```

So Piece would iterate through its Tiles calling the first method, and then if all OK, move the Tiles calling the second method.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I tried what you said (please see above), but it's still giving me similar issues. The print statements show that: 1) the new positions are being accurately calculated and stored, 2) the old positions are set to null... Then I set the location of the blocks to the new location. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Growler: you're still doing things in the wrong order. Again, your Piece class must first check ***all*** the Tiles to see if they are movable. It shouldn't move **any** Tiles at this point. If all are OK, then it should move ***all*** Tiles. Again this is nothing but simple logic. Think through the problem and you'll see this makes sense.

Comment: Any thoughts Hovercraft? I've made some updates above. Thanks!